# How does a phased rollout affect the current version number on the app store

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I am using `"http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?bundleId="` to query information about my app to get the current highest available version and check if a user needs to update their app.  It works but i'm concerned what will happen during a phased roll out of my app.  I do not want to prompt the user to update if the update isn't available for them yet.

I want to know at what point during a phased rollout will the appstore (and by extension this API call) will begin to display the new version as the highest version number (and therefor prompt the user to update).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As soon as you release the app for distribution the store will reflect the new version (technically, there can be a few hours delay between release and the store updating), since that is the version that new users will get (it wouldn't make sense to distribute an old version only to require an update almost immediately).

The phased release only manages automatic updates. A user can always update manually to the latest version. You can safely inform any user of an available update as they will be see the new version in the App Store.